# epilog of function in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, decompiling

When I decompile Mips program I saw that the epilog function looks like

```
jr      $ra
addiu   $sp, 80
```

I understand the stack frame (size of stack)of this function is 80.

But if the program jump to $ra (jr $ra). How the program arrive to the next line?

Comment: That's a [delay slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot). The instruction there is executed before the jump.

Comment: I can recommend [Raymond Chen's series of blog posts about the MIPS R4000](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180402-00/?p=98415). At the end you should find links to the next article each time. Delay slots come at parts 9-11 but I encourage you to give the whole thing a read (and just skip sections that you already understand) :)